# Nested array delete nil

Tags: ruby, arrays, null

I have nested array like this:

```
['foo', [nil], 'baz', ['bar'], nil, ['zoo']]
```

as elegantly remove `nil` but leave empty arrays?*
I expect to see:

```
['foo', [], 'baz', ['bar'], ['zoo']]
```

Any help masters?

*one iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do as below :

```
a = ['foo', [nil], 'baz', ['bar'], nil, ['zoo']]
a.map { |e| e.is_a?(Array) ? e.compact : e }.compact
# => ['foo', [], 'baz', ['bar'], ['zoo']]
```

Update:

```
a.map { |e| e.instance_of?(Array) ? e.compact : e }.compact
```

more clean `instance_of?`, returns `true` if the object is an instance of that exact class, not a subclass.

Comment: yes it is like `a.map! {|v| (v.compact if v.is_a? Array) || v }.compact`, but `is_a?` is unclear. have other thoughts?

Comment: @Monk_Code I changed.. more clear `#instance_of?` :)

Comment: @majioa Done!! people choice!! :)

Comment: @Monk_Code If you don't like `is_a?`, then use `a.map { |e| e.instance_of?(Array) ? e.compact : e }.compact`

Comment: more clean `instance_of?`, returns true if the object is an instance of that exact class, not a subclass.

Answer (score 4):

Try the code:

```
array = ['foo', [nil], 'baz', ['bar'], nil, ['zoo']]
array.map! {|v| v.is_a?( Array ) && v.compact || v }.compact
# => ["foo", [], "baz", ["bar"], ["zoo"]]
```

or more flexible:

```
array.map! {|v| v.respond_to?( :compact ) && v.compact || v }.compact
# => ["foo", [], "baz", ["bar"], ["zoo"]]
```

or with trap:

```
array.map! {|v| v.compact rescue v }.compact
# => ["foo", [], "baz", ["bar"], ["zoo"]]
```

Comment: I don't know how many people rely on *inline rescue*.. There is a risk.

Answer (score 2):

And here is an recursive version that works with deeper nesting:

```
a =  ['foo', [nil, [nil, nil, [nil, 1, 2]]], 'baz', ['bar'], nil, ['zoo']]

def recursive_conpact(arr)
   arr.is_a?(Array) ? arr.compact.map{|x|recursive_conpact(x)} : arr
end

p recursive_conpact(a) #=> ["foo", [[[1, 2]]], "baz", ["bar"], ["zoo"]]
```